# How would I use entity wrapper to insert new values into an entity property list? bundle?

Tags: entities

I would like to save a list of values into a entity property.

```
foreach ($results as $result)
{
   $wrapper->title->set(value);
}
```

Can an entity property hold an array of values or would I use an entity reference defined as a field for each of my values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field can only hold multiple values if it's been explicitly set to hold more than one value (this is an option when creating the field - see "How many values the field will store" at http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui ). In that case, the correct syntax using the entity metadata wrapper is to use array operator [] as follow:

```
$tids = array(....);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', node_load(1));
foreach ($tids as $tid) {
  $wrapper->field_taxonomy[] = $tid;
}
```

Please note that in your original example you use the field 'title' - however that is a special drupal field, and it cannot be made to be multi-valued.

Comment: Also, if you're setting a term_reference field. The format needs to be $wrapper->field_term_ref['und'][] = array('tid' => TID);

Comment: @donutdan4114 - that is how you access a entity object, NOT an entity metadata wrapper. The whole point of entity metadata wrappers is that you don't deal with things such as language directly. See https://drupal.org/node/1021556

Comment: Thanks for the info! So are you able to use the entity_metadata_wrapper on an entity that has not been saved yet?